# setheight() not changing the variable

Tags: java, syntax

I'm going over Java tutorials and I got stuck. 
when I execute wall.setHeight(-1.5)
its returning me 4 instead of 0 for the height.
can anyone tell me what is wrong with my syntax?

```
public class Wall {
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public Wall(){
        System.out.println("Empty");

    }

    public Wall(double width, double height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        System.out.println("width=" + this.width + "height=" + this.height);
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        if((this.width)<0){
            this.width =  0.00;
        }
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        System.out.println("got here ");
        if((this.height)<0){
            this.height =  0.00;
        }
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getArea(){
        return (this.width) * (this.height);
    }
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wall wall = new Wall(5,4);
        System.out.println("area= " + wall.getArea());
        wall.setHeight(-1.5);
        System.out.println(wall.getHeight());
        System.out.println("width= " + wall.getWidth());
        System.out.println("height= " + wall.getHeight());
        System.out.println("area= " + wall.getArea());**
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't set `width` and `height` in their corresponding setters.

Comment: your `if` statement in the setter prevent height values < 0 being set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your `setHeight()` method with input of "-1.5", do this:

```
public void setHeight(double height) {
    System.out.println("got here ");
    if (height < 0) {        // use "height" instead of "this.height"
        this.height = 0.00;
    }
}
```

To fix it so that it also saves other, zero-or-greater values, do this;

```
public void setHeight(double height) {
    System.out.println("got here ");
    if (height < 0) {
        this.height = 0.00;
    } else {
        this.height = height;   // set a new value for "this.height" if you didn't zero it out above
    }
}
```

The confusion you ran into is when to use `height` as opposed to `this.height`. One of them represents the parameter value being passed into the method (`height`), and the other represents the value already stored on the object (`this.height`).

Also, if you use an IDE (such as IntelliJ), you would see the "height" variable name grayed out along with hover text *"Parameter 'height' is never used"* which would give you a clue that you have a programming error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is why I always suggest passing in a variable with a different name than the variable you are setting. You are checking if `this.height` < 0... naturally it will be whatever you set it to in the constructor.

**`this.height` will refer to the variable `height` of your Wall object, not the `height` that is passed in to the setter.**

Try this:

```
public void setHeight(double h) {
  if(h < 0) {
    this.height =  0.00;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public void setHeight(double height) {
        System.out.println("got here ");
        if((this.height)<0){
            this.height =  0.00;
        }
        else{
          this.height = height;
        } 
    }
```